# Script Not working from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need to close the download window(opened using jquery framedialog) after clicking the download button inside the content page of the framedialog. I am creating a seperate iframe for sending download file in response like this:(Download.aspx sends the file to client based on file id)

```
var script = @"<script language=JavaScript>function Export(fileID)
                            {
                                    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                                    iframe.src = 'DownloadForm.aspx?ID='+ fileID;
                                    iframe.style.display = 'none';
                                    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                                    //alert('AlertBox'); 
                            }
                            </script>"; 
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Startup", script);
```

After completing download i am closing the download window.
But my problem is that if i use the commented alertBox then my both codes works (download and close) fine. But i want it to happen without alert box. When i do not use alert box the Download.aspx page is not called. (I think the script is not going to client side while i register it and alert box is making it do something)..Dont know why its happening ..kindly help..Thanks in advance

Comment: seems like delay is only thing that alert does

Comment: @Toms..i didnt get how to use delay(ms) in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to my problem. Basically i was closing the download window before the downloading is completed at client's end.
So, i added the frame for downloading(hidden) the file in the parent page of download window and then i close the download window

Comment: basically the alert box was just stopping the code which was used to close the current download window untill we respond to alert box. And in that time the downloading was done

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(getType(), "Startup", script, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can instead, use:

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "StartupScript", script, true);`

Where `script` is:

```
var script = @"function Export(fileID)
                            {
                                    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                                    iframe.src = 'DownloadForm.aspx?ID='+ fileID;
                                    iframe.style.display = 'none';
                                    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                                    //alert('AlertBox'); 
                            }
                            //Export(YourFileIDHere);";
```

However, you should also note that the code only defines a function to be included in the script. You do not call this function anywhere in your JS code. (So I've included a commented code which can be uncommented for the function to execute, with proper `fileID`.

Comment: sorry i didnt mention the calling part :                                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Exportfile", "<script type='text/javascript'>Export('" + sFilename + "');</script>");

Comment: @samsam123 use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript() the way I've used instead of `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), ".. `

Answer (score 1):

Use this..

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "function   name", true);
```

For your Case it will be.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "Export(file Id);", true);
```

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Exportfile", "<script type='text/javascript'>Export('" + sFilename + "');</script>");

Comment: still no  results....evrything is working fine if i use alert box inside my script....